# Почему не работает slick?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, slider, slick.js

Не понимаю почему не работает slick slider.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/slick-1.8.1/slick/slick.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/slick-1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
</head>
```

```
<div class="teachers__slider">
        <div class="slide">
            <div class="text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Tempora adipisci quis sint eaque iste illum
                sunt possimus et tempore optio!
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <div class="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius mollitia veritatis quos optio tempora at
            corporis hic dicta fugit quam!
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/slick-1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

```
$(function () {

    $('teachers_slider').slick()

})
```

Comment: потому что `$('teachers_slider')` это `<teachers_slider></teachers_slider>` а не `<div class="teachers_slider"></div>`

Comment: а `teachers_slider` это вдобавок не `teachers__slider`

Comment: А,  у меня было два нижних подчеркивания, просто я эксперементировал и забыл поменять.
Тогда что мне нужно сделать, чтобы он заработал?

Comment: `$('.teachers__slider')`

Comment: Лучший, бро, спасибо!